# Where can I get an open source Radio driver and RIL for an android phone?

Tags: android, open-source, ril

I am looking for a phone (preferably android) where I can use software to have full control over the cellular radio hardware. anyone know of such a device? preferably a popular device on the market :)

My last topic on this was rather rapidly closed for unusual reasons
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961637/for-what-android-phone-is-the-ril-and-radio-driver-open-source-closed

"Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way"

My question is looking for some software to do some programing on! how much more related can you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the past, I've got the Android RIL (which I think is opensource) to work perfectly on my HTC Hero. I've since then sold it but I can remember it worked flawlessly. [These guys](http://replicant.us/) do their best to put only free software on their Android devices and it works pretty well for the HTC G1 and the Nexus One.

You can also catch them on #replicant on irc.freenode.net, they're pretty good at what they do and I think they could point you to a wider range of devices.

Comment: Thanks for that. Sorry about the delay in marking this correct! This project still seems to be moving along well. My next phone will be from their supported devices list.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for since Some Assembly Required(tm), but the OMAP Zoom dev kits can use modem modules with open-source RILs from Infineon and Enfora.

Check these links for more info:

[Modems for OMAP kits](http://omappedia.org/wiki/Modem_for_OMAP)

[Zoom2 kit](http://www.logicpd.com/products/development-kits/texas-instruments-zoom%E2%84%A2-omap34x-ii-mdp#tabs-som-1)

[Blaze kit](http://omapworld.com/blaze.html)

[Infineon X-GOLD RIL source](http://dev.omapzoom.org/?p=modem-int/xgold-ril.git;a=summary)

[Enfora EDG0308 RIL source](http://omapzoom.org/?p=platform/hardware/enfora/edg308-ril.git;a=summary)

[Other OMAP dev kits](http://omapworld.com/platforms.html)